# Bayesian Optimization for a multi-dimensional vector

Tags: python, numpy, mathematical-optimization

I get difficulties when trying to use Bayesian Optimization package (https://github.com/fmfn/BayesianOptimization) for parameter optimization. The target function is of input vector, which is a 10-dimensional vector and the constrain that each entry is between (-2,2), is as following.

```
def black_box_function(vector):
    s = 0
    for i in range (0, 10):
        s = s + vector[i]/(vector[i+1] + vector[i+2])

    return s

from bayes_opt import BayesianOptimization
pbounds = {'vector': (-2*np.ones(10), 2*np.ones(10))}

optimizer = BayesianOptimization(
    f=black_box_function,
    pbounds=pbounds,
    verbose=2, 
    random_state=1,
)

optimizer.maximize(
    init_points=2,
    n_iter=3,
)
```

But it gets the error:

```
|  iter    |  target   |  vector   |
-------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_4116\2141365244.py in <module>
      8 )
      9 
---> 10 optimizer.maximize(
     11     init_points=2,
     12     n_iter=3,

D:\Code\bayes_opt\bayesian_optimization.py in maximize(self, init_points, n_iter, acquisition_function, acq, kappa, kappa_decay, kappa_decay_delay, xi, **gp_params)
    283         self._prime_subscriptions()
    284         self.dispatch(Events.OPTIMIZATION_START)
--> 285         self._prime_queue(init_points)
    286 
    287         old_params_used = any([param is not None for param in [acq, kappa, kappa_decay, kappa_decay_delay, xi]])

D:\Code\bayes_opt\bayesian_optimization.py in _prime_queue(self, init_points)
    240 
    241         for _ in range(init_points):
--> 242             self._queue.add(self._space.random_sample())
    243 
    244     def _prime_subscriptions(self):

D:\Code\bayes_opt\target_space.py in random_sample(self)
    261         data = np.empty((1, self.dim))
    262         for col, (lower, upper) in enumerate(self._bounds):
--> 263             data.T[col] = self.random_state.uniform(lower, upper, size=1)
    264         return data.ravel()
    265 

mtrand.pyx in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.uniform()

_common.pyx in numpy.random._common.cont()

_common.pyx in numpy.random._common.cont_broadcast_2()

_common.pyx in numpy.random._common.validate_output_shape()

ValueError: Output size (1,) is not compatible with broadcast dimensions of inputs (10,).
```

I don't know how to solve this problem. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: `(10,)` is not '10 dimensional'.  What's the full error message?

Comment: @hpaulj It's the message error: ValueError: Output size (1,) is not compatible with broadcast dimensions of inputs (10,).

Comment: Is that the full message, with traceback?  In other words, you/we need to know WHERE the error occors.

Comment: @hpaulj I've added the full message errors in my question. Thank you very much in advance for your help with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bayesian optimization here works on multiple scalar arguments and this package and won't support your vector implementation. Similarly, bounds are defined on each argument rather than the vector. You could instead go about it like this:

```
labels = ["x0", "x1", "x2", ...]
pbounds = {"x0": (-2, 2), "x1": (-2, 2), ... "x9": (-2, 2)}
```

Also, you would need to modify your function to take in keyword arguments rather than a *vector* parameter.

```
def black_box_func(x0, x1, x2, ...)
```

To make this less verbose you could use ***kwargs* in your function and some dict to map the labels to their indeces.

Comment: Thanks @Matt very much. I got it. But what about if the black box function is of 100 keyword arguments instead of 10? How can use Bayesian optimization in this case? Thanks for your help again in advance.

Comment: numerically optimising a function of 100 parameters tends to be difficult, typically you'd want to constrain the problem in some way first, e.g. regularisation. even then I'd expect that this package would struggle in such high dimensions, gaussian processes are a neat tool but they have their limitations

Comment: Thank @SamMason very much for your explanation and your help.

Comment: If you’re still curious, functions in python can be defined as ‘def func(**kwargs)’ where kwargs is a dict of parameters as keys and values as arguments. This would allow you to make the dimensions dynamic

Answer (score 0):

`random.uniform` can use arrays (or lists) as range values, as well as the size.  It tries to use broadcasting to combine their effect.

For a simple case of 1 random value:

```
In [24]: np.random.uniform(0,1,size=1)
Out[24]: array([0.28895633])
```

But I get your kind of error if I give a list as a range, but ask only for one number:

```
In [25]: np.random.uniform(0,[1,2,3],size=1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[25], line 1
----> 1 np.random.uniform(0,[1,2,3],size=1)

File mtrand.pyx:1154, in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.uniform()

File _common.pyx:600, in numpy.random._common.cont()

File _common.pyx:518, in numpy.random._common.cont_broadcast_2()

File _common.pyx:245, in numpy.random._common.validate_output_shape()

ValueError: Output size (1,) is not compatible with broadcast dimensions of inputs (3,).
```

I have to ask for 3, to match the range (or omit size):

```
In [26]: np.random.uniform(0,[1,2,3],size=3)
Out[26]: array([0.3200877 , 1.24087871, 2.57545154])
```

Your error occurs deep in the imported package, so I can't readily trace the problem `uniform` parameters back to your inputs.  I believe you are setting up some parameters shapes like (1,10) or (10,10).

```
In [27]: pbounds = {'vector': (-2*np.ones(10), 2*np.ones(10))}

In [28]: pbounds
Out[28]: 
{'vector': (array([-2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2., -2.]),
  array([2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.]))}
```

Comment: Thank @hpaulj very much for your help. Indeed, there are some comments explaining that this Bayesian optimization supports only multi-scalar arguments.